# Getting F's when assigning values to registers

Tags: assembly

I'm having my first lessons in assembly programming language clearly having some gaps from other courses. I'm trying to assign values to registers with a 'MOVE' command which can move up to 16-bit signed values and this is what I noticed.

When I try to move numbers up to 7FFF it is normally moved to the register as follows: 0000 7FFFF .
When I try to move numbers from 8000 and above I get this : FFFF 8000.

My idea is that it has to do with the complement and the fact that numbers from 8 and above require 17 bits with the sign value included. If that's true why does the computer fill with F's? That's my main concern.

Comment: Because 0xf is 0b1111.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This doesn't say anything to me.I don't understand it. I know I have gaps on this and if you don't wanna go into detail I'm good with a source to study this on my own. I just don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're looking for "sign extension".

Comment: you didn't add your CPU, but I guess you are trying some kind of  `move register, immediate16` instruction, with 32 bit register and 16 bit immediate. From the described behaviour it's clear the `move` in such case does sign-extend the 16b value to set whole 32b register. On x86 platform you may check docs about `movsx` and related questions. Your value `0x8000` is then technically -32768, not +32768. And -32768 in 32 bit is `0xFFFF8000`. (so you can load values from -32768 to +32767 by that instruction). Actually you have it in your question "16 bit signed values". Check two's complement wiki

Comment: what instruction set is this and what instruction specifically did you try?